# smart-table ng-repeat not rendering dynamic columns properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, smart-table

html

```
<table st-table="ApplicationData.displayedCollection" class="table table-striped" st-safe-src="ApplicationData.source">
    <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="col in ApplicationData.columns">
            <td st-sort="{{col.name}}">{{col.caption}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

js

```
$scope.ApplicationData = {
source: [],
displayedCollection: [],
columns: [{ name: 'APPLICATION_CODE', caption: 'Code', isSort: true },
        { name: 'APPLICATION_NAME', caption: 'Application', isSort: true   }],
};
```

output

```
<table st-table="ApplicationData.displayedCollection" class="table table-striped" st-safe-src="ApplicationData.source">
    <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="col in ApplicationData.columns" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Code</td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="col in ApplicationData.columns" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Application</td></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Hi, I am using this html to generate columns dynamically but wvery time I try I am getting dynamically generated rows instead. please review my enclosed code and let me know the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to edit the template slightly: move the ng-repeat out of the `<tr>` and into `<td>` 
change this:

```
<thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="col in ApplicationData.columns">
     <td st-sort="{{col.name}}">{{col.caption}}</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

to, for example, this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <td ng-repeat="col in ApplicationData.columns">{{col.caption}}</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

here's a jsfiddle with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/86y3yxmk/1/ 
additionally, this is a good read for what you might be trying to accomplish: https://www.codementor.io/debugging/4948713248/request-want-to-use-values-in-nested-ng-repeat

GL!